# Copying large file taking more time

Tags: java, performance, io, nio, apache-commons-httpclient

I have used code mentioned in below website but for it is always taking More than 2 mnts to upload 570MB file.

https://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/

Comment: Depending on where you upload to and depending on your bandwidth, 2 minutes is a reasonable time for that size

Comment: I am uploading zip file to soap service using Apache commons httpClient

Comment: What's the question? Does something indicate that the limit is not coming from the Soap service? Can you upload a file of that size to it faster using some other technique?

Comment: Yes I have tested using SOAPUI , we can able to upload same file within 40 seconds using SOAPUI.